# Como realizar uma consulta dupla no laravel?

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-eloquent

Tenho uma query em SQL Ansi:

```
select * from payments as P, receipts as R 
where P.created_at < CURRENT_DATE AND P.updated_at < CURRENT_DATE AND R.created_at < CURRENT_DATE AND R.updated_at < CURRENT_DATE
```

Precioso realizar a mesma consulta no laravel:

```
public function relatorioBI(){

        //1 A pagar

        $query = $this->newQuery();

        $query->where('created_at','1');

        return $this->doQuery($query, $take, $paginate);
    }
```

Preciso realiza a consulta nas duas tabelas, e testar o valor condicional!

Comment: Você pode utilizar \DB::select!

Comment: Tem algum exemplo para demonstrar???

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=DB%3A%3Aselect alguns exemplos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use o [`\DB::select`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/database#running-queries) que a maneira simples de realizar consultas dessa forma:

***Exemplo:***

```
$sql = ' select * from payments as P, receipts as R ';
$sql .= ' where P.created_at < CURRENT_DATE AND P.updated_at < CURRENT_DATE ';
$sql .= ' AND R.created_at < CURRENT_DATE AND R.updated_at < CURRENT_DATE';

$users = \DB::select($sql);
```

***Observação:*** no [site já existe vários exemplos veja link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=DB%3A%3Aselect).

Se precisa utilizar parâmetros siga um exemplo da documentação do [laravel](/questions/tagged/laravel):

```
\DB::select('select * from users where active = ?', [1]);
```

***ou seja***, um `array` conforme a sequencia e quantidade de parâmetro (`?`).

***Referencia:*** [Running Raw SQL Queries](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/database#running-queries)